# Trademark superscript in NSI

Tags: unicode, nsis, symbols, superscript

I want to add a Trade Mark superscript in the NSI script.

I tried using unicode character for trademark - `U+2122` , but it doesn't display the trade mark character correctly when the installer exe is run?

I have following questions:

1. How do I add the trademark symbol in the NSI
2. I am using NSI compiler version 2.46 . Do I need to upgrade?
3. How to create (enable) unicode support in a NSI file?

Answer (score 2):

Source files in NSIS 2 are just a bunch of bytes and these bytes are stored directly in the .exe. At run-time Windows will (on NT based systems) convert these bytes to Unicode strings by using the current codepage/system locale (Language for non-unicode programs). This means that you have to use the correct codepage/encoding in your text editor. If your installer supports multiple languages you need to use `LangString` and basically edit those strings with the correct encoding set in your editor. Using a .nsh for each language might help.

NSIS 3 uses Unicode internally in the compiler and if you are creating a Unicode installer (`Unicode True`) then you can use any Unicode code point. You can save the .nsi as UTF-8 or UTF-16 (with BOM) or you can use the ${U+hexnumber} syntax:

```
Unicode True
Section
MessageBox mb_ok "Hello World${U+2122}" 
SectionEnd
```

NSIS 3 can also generate Ansi installers and it knows about the ${U+hexnumber} syntax but it cannot guarantee that the codepoint will display correctly on the end-users system, it is still limited to simple bytes and will convert from Unicode to Ansi using the current codepage from the system you are compiling on.

Comment: I managed to show an exponent ² saving the .NSI as UTF8, however in plain ANSI text .NSI the equivalent ${U+0178} produces the wrong text (some Y symbol) -- even when saved as UTF8!?

Comment: @nikos 0x178 is "Ÿ Latin Capital Letter Y with Diaeresis". These Unicode codepoints are usually in hex, try ${U+00B2}.

Comment: that did it, thanks! you are such a helpful guy, enjoy the beer :)

Comment: @nikos Thanks, I will. I'm a fan of your shell work and blog, it's all good =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the character `0x99`, the Windows 1252 equivalent of `U+2122`.

With a western configured windows, you can enter it directly via the  keyboard with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> (keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed while entering the digits on the numeric keypad, and it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> and **not** <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>).